# double click copy contents of adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

I need a simple code which will copy contents of adjacent left cell to double clicked cell. This is to help me in making entries as in attached image.

If I click `c2` it should copy 3 from `b2` and paste it in `c2`, and it should do it for `c2: c100`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")

    With ws1
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("b2:b100")) Is Nothing Then
            Cancel = True

            If Application.CountIf(Sheets(ws1).Range("b2:b100"), Target.Value) = 0 Then
                Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value = Target.Value
            
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C2:C100")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        Target.Value = Target.Offset(, -1).Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Me = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")
i added above two lines in your code, still doesnt work

Comment: No need to refer to workbook neither worksheet as the code is put in worksheet module not in standard module. How did you put the code and in which column did you double-click?

Comment: can you please tell me how to put code in worksheet module instead of standard module

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this - note in the worksheet code module, you can use `Me` to refer to the worksheet.

Technically you don't need to qualify the `Range()`, since in a worksheet module it defaults to that sheet, but it's good practice to always qualify where you can.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C2:C100")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        with Target.Offset(0, -1)
            If Len(.Value) > 0 Then Target.Value = .Value
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: it doesnt work, Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Me = wb.Worksheets("sheet1")
i added these two lines in ur code, still doesnt

Comment: You have to put the code in the worksheet code module